# Merging two Dictionaries in Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3, sprig-template-functions

I am using **Helm 3**. I have two `values.yaml` files. In `common/values.yaml` I have defined:

```
deployment:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
```

The `common` is of the type `library`. In `my-app`, which is of the type `application`, the `common` is added as a dependency. In `my-app/values.yaml` I have added:

```
deployment:
  ports:
    - containerPort: 8081
```

I have defined a template `_deployment.yaml` in `common/templates`. In this file I am trying to merge these two `deployment` dictionaries into one by using:

```
{{- $deployment := merge .Values.common.deployment .Values.deployment -}}
```

When I am printing `{{ $deployment }}`, it is giving output:

```
map[ports:[map[containerPort:8080 name:http protocol:TCP]]]
```

And if I do:

```
{{- $deployment := merge .Values.deployment .Values.common.deployment -}}
```

The output of `{{ $deployment }}` is:

```
map[ports:[map[containerPort:8081]]]
```

Moreover the output of `{{ .Values.common.deployment }}` is:

```
map[ports:[map[name:http protocol:TCP]]]
```

And the output of `{{ .Values.deployment }}` is:

```
map[ports:[map[containerPort:8081]]]
```

What I would like to have after merging is:

```
deployment:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      containerPort: 8081
```

Any advice you could give would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the merge operation does not work as expected on lists (it's a common problem, as the merge operation is ambiguous on list: should a list be appended or replaced when merging ?)

Anyway, I would suggest to merge the ports data with:

```
{{- $ports := merge .Values.deployment.ports[0] .Values.common.deployment.ports[0] -}}
```

and render the result with:

```
  deployment:
    ports:
      - {{- toJson $ports }}
```

HTH